# How can i make my transition stay on active link?

Tags: html, css

I want to have line animation over my 'li's' in my menu, and I have, but then I want to make the animation stay on active link.

My code:

```
.menu ul li:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0%;
  color: #f7f7f7;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
  border-image-slice: 1;
  transition: width .5s ease-in-out 0s;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.menu ul li:focus:before,
.menu ul li:hover:before {
  color: #f7f7f7;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to right, #529ecc , #9CF5A6);
  border-image-slice: 1;
  width: 100%;
```

EDIT: I added .active, but I think I have to go into javascript in this, because I do not want to make animation over the link that is active --> then I have both, line over active plus animation when I hover over active link.

Active code:

```
.menu ul li.active {
  color: #f7f7f7;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to right, #529ecc , #9CF5A6);
  border-image-slice: 1;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
```

Comment: Do it on the `a` element instead, or add a `tabindex` attribute to the lis so they can receive focus, and then use the `:active` pseudoselector.

Comment: I think you mis-understand `:active`, `:active` is call when you press/click on the link, and it stop and goto the link, it doesn't mean the link your currently on.

Comment: `:active` works one links. When you are still clicking on the link. Press down and it will work, but as soon as you lift your finger, the link is no longer active.'

Comment: You will have to use `javascript/jQuery/PHP`/etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is kind of an answer... This might help you with what you actually want to do. This will apply a class to whatever link you click, letting you style it however you like. It uses `jQuery` though it can be written in pure `javascript` if desired. It could also be accomplished with `PHP` or some other server-side scripting language.

The `CSS` psudo-class `:active` will not work with what you are trying to do.

**EDIT**: add `:not(.active)` to the css rules so that it is not applied to the `active` link. Code changed in my edit.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".menu li a", function(e) {
  //This removes the `active` class from all `a`
  $(".menu li a").removeClass("active");

  //This adds the `active` class to the `a` that was clicked on
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.active {
  background: #ffbf00;
}

.menu ul li a:not(.active):before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0%;
  color: #f7f7f7;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
  border-image-slice: 1;
  transition: width .5s ease-in-out 0s;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.menu ul li a:not(.active):focus:before,
.menu ul li a:not(.active):hover:before {
  color: #f7f7f7;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to right, #529ecc , #9CF5A6);
  border-image-slice: 1;
  width: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='menu'>
  <ul>
    <li><a href='#'>Page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Page 2</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Page 3</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Page 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It does not help; when I hover over an active link I do not want to hover animation to show, just on the rest of the links; I've tried to make some javascript :                                                          
              $(document).on("hover", ".menu li a", function(e) {
 
  $(".menu li a").removeClass("hover");

  
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
but i don't know how :/

Comment: @SadFrodo I'm not sure what you mean... My example has no hovering styles.

Comment: Yes, I know, but maybe You can help me with that - I have got two classes : one with transition that when i hover over menu item there is line over it and second, active class, that when an item is active, there is line over it; but at the same time, when I hover over active item, the hover animation shows - and I don't want that

Comment: @SadFrodo Look at my edit. I added the `:not(.active)` to the css. This means that the `:hover` and `:focus` will only be applied to the `a` that do not also have the class `active`.

Comment: Thank You VERY much! I didn't know about the not(.class) at all!

Comment: @SadFrodo No problem. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Actually [**:active** selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active) only affects the element when it's clicked and then goes away and the link gets its initial style as far as you release it.

**Solution:**

You need to use a custom class for example `active` and use it with your active element, you will set it in your CSS like this:

```
.menu ul li.active{
      //Your style goes here
}
```

But you will need JavaScript to toggle this class in the clicked `li` element.