# Is there any way to make a button click's `:active` animation last longer?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

Here is the requirement.
When a user clicks on the button, I want to change its box-shadow so the user has a feedback to their click.
Keeping this in mind, I tried the following solution:

```css
button {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  transition: box-shadow 0.4s;
}

button:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px 4px rgba(173, 216, 230, 1)
}
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>
```

As can be seen from the value of the `transition` style, I want this animation to last 0.4 seconds.
However, this does not seem to work and when the button is clicked the box-shadow change is not even visible. I think it's because the button press is shorter than 0.4 seconds.

Can anyone tell me a good way to make sure the animation stays for 0.4s or the box-shadow stays for 0.4 seconds so the user can get feedback on his click?

Here is a codepen: https://codepen.io/AnirudhMS/pen/MWXWNNz (using 1s for the transition-duration to make the issue clearer)

Comment: Your code is working fine. It's just that `:active` is only applied while you actually keep mouse button down on button. Try clicking and keeping it clicked, will see it's working. `transition` means how fast CSS changes between states

Comment: Yes. That was my understanding as well. However, the question I have is, is there a way I can make sure that the transition lasts the desired amount of time on button click?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i make my transition stay on active link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43525693/how-can-i-make-my-transition-stay-on-active-link)

Comment: Yes, with JS add class and after fixed period of time remove it

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code and it worked as you've expected.
try to show me your actual code.

and if you're using any framework try to use the important flag so your code should be like that.

```
button:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px 4px rgba(173, 216, 230, 1) !important;
}
```

Comment: Check the codepen I have linked above. I have changed the transition-duration to 1s so the result is a lot clearer.

Comment: @BlackWind But 1 second is a  bit slow, don't you think.
make it 0.1s so it can be faster.